# Sending Hidden Data to URL and get response in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, payment-gateway

Dears,

I'm new in Laravel, and i need to integrate a payment gateway provided by https://www.netcommercepay.com/

the URL is: https://www.netcommercepay.com/iPAY/

I need to send hidden data to this URL and get response in Laravel.

How to do this ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: you create a post request to that url

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by 'hidden data'? Send from where?

Comment: You need to use POST in form. And use <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100" /> Like that. I can't find any developer docs on netcommercepay.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware from my view, i have somedate like amount, name, etc..., i need to send them as hidden like (<input type="hidden">)

Comment: OK, but just remember that these form inputs are only visibly hidden, the data is still accessible to the user, for instance by inspecting the source code. They can even be changed. As said before, simply submit the form to the given URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" url="https://www.netcommercepay.com/iPAY/">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ $amount }}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $name }}" />
</form>
```

Like that add hidden values. Add this in your blade file. There will some other values like merchat id inorder to work the payment processor.

To get the response you need to add a route and controller method. I can't see any documentation at the site. Maybe you need to login to see the docs.

Add some validation at the IPN to check the user sent correct amount. There will be some signature or hash verification to prevent fraud.